# Не работает скрипт на React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Начал учить React. Создал первый скрипт, но почему то он ничего не выводит и я не могу понять в чем проблема.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

      <div id="example"></div>

      <script type="text/babel">

        ReactDOM.render (
          <div><h3>Hi, it's me!</h3></div>, 
          document.getElementById("example")
        );
      
      </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не знаю, я копирую ваш код, у меня все работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё работает. Возможно, дело в том, что ты открываешь страницу как локальный файл, а не через сервер. Хотя, по идее для inline-скриптов разницы быть не должно.

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="example"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render (
    <div><h3>Hi, it's me!</h3></div>, 
    document.getElementById("example")
  );
</script>
```